# Does extra reservoir increases my arcanist's daily points forever?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, class-feature

The feat from Advanced Class Guide, [extra reservoir](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedClassGuide/feats.html#extra-reservoir):

> **Benefit:** You gain three more points in your arcane reservoir, and the maximum number of points in your arcane reservoir increases by that amount.

Is this first 3-point increase the daily amount, forever? or just when the feat is acquired?

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, it increases your daily limit and your pool.

The feat works exactly like [Extra Lay on Hands](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/extra-lay-on-hands-final/) or [Extra Rage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/extra-rage-final/), granting your an increase in your pool. Feats generally provide permanent increases to your character, and this one is no exception.

Example, you are a first level arcanist, which nets you a maximum limit of 4 points (3 + level), and a daily recharge of 3 (3 + half level). If you take *Extra Reservoir*, this increases to 7 maximum and 6 daily recharge. This may sound like a lot, but feats are generally powerful at the starting levels. Later on, say 10th level, you would have 13 maximum and 8 recharge without the feat, but 16 maximum and 11 recharge if you take the feat. The advantage is not so great anymore.

Comment: The phrasing on Extra Lay on Hands/Rage is slightly different to Extra Reservoir. Extra Reservoir still provides a permanent bonus to your character, even if it doesn't increase the daily recharge. Do you have something to back up your statement that this feat increases your recharge?

Comment: **Arcane Reservoir** is how this pool is called, there is no term for the daily recharge number, that is something I made up so its better to understand and explain the ability. See *Each day, when the arcanist prepares spells, the arcanist's arcane reservoir fills with raw magical energy, gaining a number of points equal to 3 + 1/2 her arcanist level. Any points she had from the previous day are lost.*